# Citing literature review APA

Tags: citations, citation-style

I am mentioning briefly research topic that has reached a general consensus and cite a literature review paper. I wonder which of the two ways below provides in terms of the best readability. I dislike both options and suspect I am missing the optimal option.

blabla.... a group of study has found strong association....

1. See `Smith and Pitt (1999)` for overview.
2. See `(Smith and Pitt, 1999)` for overview.
3. See `????` for overview

I am following APA standard but not literary so style improvements are more important.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it deals with the APA style guide and not within academics as defined by this site.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. My main concern is not with the standard but rather readability and have tried to update the questions accordingly.

Comment: @RoboKaren: I don't think there is a need to close this question. This very well fits in the guidelines (refer [tag:citation-style]). Many questions under a similar context have been asked before.

Comment: In my opinion, _"see [citation] for overview"_ or similar represents a poor writing style. It is OK for informal writing, however, in a formal write-up (using APA or any other style, for that matter), using the following style is much more preferred: _"... [topic/subject] is extensively covered in research literature, including several comprehensive reviews (Smith & Pitt, 1999; ...) ..."_.

Answer (score 2):

The first form is more common in [APA style format](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/560/02/).

> See Smith and Pitt (1999) for overview.

Although I would be more picky in the use of *'see'*. The word *'refer'* would be used to point to a reference where a point is taken from or pointing to further readings. While *'see'* is used to point to a reference that supports your claim (kindly refer [this post](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/71046/the-usage-of-citation-signals-such-as-see-commonly-used/75450#75450)).

Having said the above, both *see* and *refer* are used interchangeably in practice with the nuances not kept in mind.